How to remove git:[git@github.com .git] in pycharm terminal
In my PyCharm command line, I have this prompt: (.venv) ~/PycharmProjects/myBinanceTrade git:[git@github.com-kalimero76/webService.git]. How can I remove the git:[git@github.com-kalimero76/webService.git] part from the prompt?
I have tried searching through the PyCharm settings and the project's configuration files but couldn't find an option to remove the Git information from the prompt. I was expecting to find a straightforward setting or command that would allow me to customize the command line prompt to exclude the Git details.
